# Change tooltip text color of Ubuntu Vimix theme

Tags: themes, text, css, tooltip

I am on Ubuntu Budgie 18.10 and trying to adjust the colors of the [Vimix theme](https://github.com/vinceliuice/vimix-gtk-themes).

Especially, I want to change the foreground and background (text) colors of the tooltip popups.

Editing the GTK3 css file, I found the section * Tooltips * (line 4016 onward).

Changing background works as expected:

```
tooltip.background {
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
   background-color: red;
}
```

But changing the tooltip item, I have added the line "color: #FFFFFF, does not affect the text color.

```
tooltip {
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Neither does adding:

```
tooltip.foreground{
  color: #00C853;
}
```

Or:

```
@define-color theme_tooltip_fg_color #FFFFFF;
```

Any idea of how to change text color of the tooltips?

EDITED : including header bars

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the one you are looking for is `tooltip label`

```
tooltip label {
  color: green;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 0 2px;
}
```

[image]

seems to be there are more colors configured for header-bar and title-bars in different conditions in this vimix gtk.3-0 css file.

some i found are below, if you want them in single color, make all feilds same color.

***Black***

```
window.tiled headerbar, window.tiled headerbar:first-child, window.tiled headerbar:last-child, window.tiled headerbar:only-child,
window.tiled-top headerbar,
window.tiled-top headerbar:first-child,
window.tiled-top headerbar:last-child,
window.tiled-top headerbar:only-child,
window.tiled-right headerbar,
window.tiled-right headerbar:first-child,
window.tiled-right headerbar:last-child,
window.tiled-right headerbar:only-child,
window.tiled-bottom headerbar,
window.tiled-bottom headerbar:first-child,
window.tiled-bottom headerbar:last-child,
window.tiled-bottom headerbar:only-child,
window.tiled-left headerbar,
window.tiled-left headerbar:first-child,
window.tiled-left headerbar:last-child,
window.tiled-left headerbar:only-child,
window.maximized headerbar,
window.maximized headerbar:first-child,
window.maximized headerbar:last-child,
window.maximized headerbar:only-child,
window.fullscreen headerbar,
window.fullscreen headerbar:first-child,
window.fullscreen headerbar:last-child,
window.fullscreen headerbar:only-child,
window.solid-csd headerbar,
window.solid-csd headerbar:first-child,
window.solid-csd headerbar:last-child,
window.solid-csd headerbar:only-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
background-color: black;
}
```

Black background
[image]

***Blue***

```
.titlebar:not(headerbar),
headerbar {
  transition: background-color 100ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1), color 100ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
  min-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
}
```

Blue background
[image]

***Yellow***

```
.titlebar:backdrop:not(headerbar),
headerbar:backdrop {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

***Red***

```
.titlebar, .titlebar.background {
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
background-color: red;
}
```

Yellow & Red Backgrounds
[image]

Comment: Right in front of me .. silly me. Thanks, @PRATAP

Comment: Do you know, by the way, how to style the background color of the window headerbars? I can only find titlebar:not(headerbar) ....

Comment: In the same file from line 1.326 onward. Changing the title-bars seem to only affect buttons like in the nautilus tree-view, but not the windows' title bars ... I have added a screenshot.

Comment: actually I want to change the color of all windows, not only Nautilus. Thanks for your efforts. I work with Java for a couple of years, but I am only now learning css, my target for 2019. I find it a little confusing, since there seem to be few styling conventions....

Comment: This is just perfect. Many thanks for your great help.